# how to take token from http client with signalr in blazor server app?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, blazor

I using SignalR in my Blazor server app. I added `services.AddSignalR()` in startup.cs file. Then I can't take token. Because http context is `null`. Then I removed `services.AddSignalR()` from startup.cs file. it is normal working. Then i can take token from http client. How to solve it?

Thank you.

Startup.cs file:

```cs
services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
    })
    .AddCookie("Cookies")
    .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.Authority = identityUrl.ToString();
        options.SignedOutRedirectUri = callBackUrl.ToString();
        options.ClientId = useLoadTest ? "mvctest" : "blazor";
        options.ClientSecret = "secret";
        options.ResponseType = useLoadTest ? "code id_token token" : "code id_token";
        options.SaveTokens = true;
        options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        options.Scope.Add("openid");
        options.Scope.Add("profile");
        options.Scope.Add("post");
        options.Scope.Add("family");
        options.Scope.Add("webpostagg");

    });

services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddSignalR();

services.AddHttpClient<IPostService, PostService>()                  
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<HttpClientAuthorizationDelegatingHandler>();
```

**HttpClientAuthorizationDelegatingHandler.cs:**

```cs
public HttpClientAuthorizationDelegatingHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccesor)

{
    _httpContextAccesor = httpContextAccesor;
}

protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    string authorizationHeader;
    if (_httpContextAccesor.HttpContext == null)
    {
        authorizationHeader = string.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        authorizationHeader = _httpContextAccesor.HttpContext
        .Request.Headers["Authorization"];
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorizationHeader))
    {
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", new List<string>() { authorizationHeader });
    }

    var token = await GetToken();

    if (token != null)
    {
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    }

    return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}

public async Task<string> GetToken()
{
    const string ACCESS_TOKEN = "access_token";

    return await _httpContextAccesor.HttpContext
        .GetTokenAsync(ACCESS_TOKEN);
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but it works fine for me. Could you please show us how the `IPostService` is invoked?

Comment: I added following code to startup.cs file. And it's working.

Comment: options.TokenValidationParameters = new  TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        NameClaimType = "name"
                    };

                    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                    {
                        OnAccessDenied = context =>
                        {
                            context.HandleResponse();
                            context.Response.Redirect("/");
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        }
                    };

Comment: I just to deploy kubernetes. And this url is don't working (_hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("http://beta.ugiinbichig.mn/socialhub")
            .Build();) What do you think about it?

Comment: I think you need to specify the scheme : `http://...` or `https://...`

Comment: i using http : // beta.ugiinbichig.mn/socialhub

Comment: Could you please show us the error exceptions/logs?

Comment: JsonReaderException: '<' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(ref Utf8JsonReader json, ExceptionResource resource, byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan<byte> bytes)

Comment: InvalidDataException: Invalid negotiation response received.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections.NegotiateProtocol.ParseResponse(ReadOnlySpan<byte> content)

Comment: There's something wrong with the request. Where did you get the `'<' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | B`? The server should returns a JSON. But it seems returns a HTML?

Comment: i changed url http : // 23.101.19.81/posthub. it is normal working. socialhub and posthub is same. 23.101.19.81 is asp.net core mvc app. beta.ugiinbichig.mn is blazor app.

Comment: I checked using break point. And don't working hubconnection.StartAsync(). i think url is unknown. what do you think about hubconnection.withUrl?

Comment: I'm really confused. Is there a minimal demo that reproduces the same issue?

Comment: i don't have any demo. what do you think about subdomain? is it okey?

Comment: i just changed _hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("http : //23.101.19.81/posthub")
            .Build();. it is working.

Comment: @itminus I found my mistake :). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, do not use HttpContext in Server Blazor App. It is not available. Server-side Blazor is WebSocket-based, not HTTP requests based. Just don't do that.

Here are links to my answer how to implement OpenID Connect, and others, where you'll find answers to your questions.

See these:
[how to jwt authentication blazor server without microsoft identity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59922302/how-to-jwt-authentication-blazor-server-without-microsoft-identity/59923025#59923025)
[How do I get the access token from a blazor (server-side) web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59891352/how-do-i-get-the-access-token-from-a-blazor-server-side-web-app/59901672#59901672)
[How to add OpenIdConnect via IdentityServer4 to ASP.NET Core ServerSide Blazor web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59638965/how-to-add-openidconnect-via-identityserver4-to-asp-net-core-serverside-blazor-w/59672926#59672926)
[How to get JWT authenticated sign-in user from identity claims in asp.net web api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59588674/how-to-get-jwt-authenticated-sign-in-user-from-identity-claims-in-asp-net-web-ap/59589908#59589908)
[How to use the HttpContext object in server-side Blazor to retrieve information about the user, user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59538318/how-to-use-the-httpcontext-object-in-server-side-blazor-to-retrieve-information/59538319#59538319)
[Blazor Adding HttpClientHandler to add Jwt to HTTP Header on requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57608328/blazor-adding-httpclienthandler-to-add-jwt-to-http-header-on-requests/57609864#57609864)

[Blazor: Redirect to Login page when there is no session / JWT token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55401138/blazor-redirect-to-login-page-when-there-is-no-session-jwt-token/55403870#55403870)

Note: There are more answers related to Jwt,OpenID Connect, etc. You just have to look for them

Comment: Thank you. I found my mistake.

Comment: The guy here is literally using HttpContext: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59891352/how-do-i-get-the-access-token-from-a-blazor-server-side-web-app/59901672#59901672

Comment: That guy is me: display name: enet